# What position axially within a solenoid gives the maximum magnetic force?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, inductance

Assuming an infinitely long shaft, which is held stationary at a given position in the coil, where should interface Y be positioned along length x such that the plunger experiences the maximum force from the coil's magnetic field?

(Assume everything is idealised - i.e. a perfectly homogenous coil density, perfectly homogenous plunger halves with one ferromagnetic and the other perfectly non-magnetic, perfectly aligned plunger down the central axis of the coil, etc.)

Many thanks for the help

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main part of the force is exerted on the interface between the ferromagnetic and the non-ferromagnetic parts, so the interface should be at the middle of the solenoid where its field is the strongest.

Comment: How confident are you about this? I would have guessed the interface should be at around 2/3 of length x as more ferromagnetic material is being attracted to the solenoid? If you can demonstrate the answer's correct, I can mark it as so, cheers

Comment: A uniform magnetic field does not exert a force on the body of a ferromagnetic bar, but does at the end where $M$ is discontinuous.